# ArrayList implementation but arrayList.size() wont update

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm triyng to solve this problem [Printer Queue](http://poj.org/problem?id=3125), but i'm new using Java and i can not seems to make it work.

My logic is basead in removing elements from the arrayList, but even after calling ´.trimToSize()´ the size dont update, what is the problem?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class PrinterQueue {

    static boolean isBiggest(ArrayList<Integer> list, int index) {
        int max_index = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            if (list.get(i) > list.get(max_index)) {
                max_index = i;
            }
        }
        return max_index == index;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sca = new Scanner(System.in);
        int number_of_int = sca.nextInt();
        for (int i = 0; i < number_of_int; i++) {
            int number_of_jobs = sca.nextInt();
            int my_job_index = sca.nextInt();

            ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(number_of_jobs);
            for (int j = 0; j < number_of_jobs; j++) {
                list.add(sca.nextInt());
            }

            int minutes_to_complete = 0;
            while(list.size() > 0) {
                System.out.println("current size: " + list.size());
                int current = list.get(0);
                if (isBiggest(list, current) && my_job_index == 0) {
                    System.out.println("1: ");
                    minutes_to_complete++;      
                    list.remove(0);
                } else {
                    if (isBiggest(list, current)) { 
                        System.out.println("2: ");
                        list.remove(0); 
                        minutes_to_complete++;      
                    } else {
                        int cache = list.get(0);
                        list.remove(0);
                        list.add(cache);
                        my_job_index--;
                        System.out.println("my_job_index:" + my_job_index);
                    }
                }
                list.trimToSize();

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your code hitting the `else` inside the `else` every time?

Comment: If so that would make sense why the list size isn't changing, you keep adding and removing an element from the list.

Comment: Note that many contest sites don't allow that problems are solved with the help of others. Please read the ToS of that site if you're unsure.

Comment: Yes, @JackRyan its keeping hitting the else-else,

Comment: @Zabuza, i'm not competing it's just for studyng, and i think that my problem is 'language-wise'.

Comment: Learn how to debug small programs like this. Place multiple small `System.out.println(...)` statements everywhere in the program to see what is called when, check if it works like you expected. Or learn how to use the debugger of your IDE to step through the code line per line. A very useful skill that makes debugging this kind of stuff easy.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the function isBiggest, i was passing the value of the element that wanted to compare and not the index as it should be.